# Why is my calling function receiving an undefined value when the called function returns an object?

Tags: node.js

The getProductById function below calls the fetchProductFromCache function. The product is fetched and is logged to the terminal in the fetchProductFromCache function. The product is then returned to the getProductById function but somehow, the value received here is undefined.

getProductById

```
exports.getProductById = async (req, res) => {
console.log('\n#### ProductService#getProductById ####')
const id = req.params.id;

try {
    let product = await fetchProductFromCache(id);
    console.log('product from redis = ', product) //product here is unedfined

    if(product == null) {
        console.log('null product = ', product)
        product = await Product.findById(id);
        setProductInCache(id, product);
        console.log('PRODUCT FROM DB ');
    }                
    res.status(200).json(product);
    return;
} catch (error) {
    new ErrorHandler(res, error);
}
}
```

fetchProductFromCache

```
const fetchProductFromCache = async (id) => {
await redisClient.getProduct(id,  (error, product) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log('error', error);
        throw error;
    } else if(product) {
        console.log('PRODUCT FROM CACHE ', product); //valid product is logged   
        return product; //product returned to getProductById
    } else {
        console.log('NO PRODUCT FROM CACHE ');    
        return null;
    }            
});
}
```

Comment: `fetchProductFromCache()` doesn't return anything. Maybe you want to return the promise from `redisClient.getProduct()`?

Comment: Would you care to expand on that.

Comment: I'm not sure what else to say. If you want to get something from the function you need to return something. This doesn't need to be an async function. Just return the promise: `return redisClient.getProduct(/*..etc*/)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because there's some issue with your `fetchProducFromCache`. (read comments)

```
const fetchProductFromCache = async (id) => {
  // ** Here redisClient.getProduct expects 2nd parameter to be a callback which you've passed as annonymous function
  // let's name it cb
  await redisClient.getProduct(id,  (error, product) => {
    ...
    } else if(product) {
      console.log('PRODUCT FROM CACHE ', product); //valid product is logged
      // This returns to cb not to fetchProductFromCache.   
      return product; //product returned to getProductById
    ...
}
```

The `cb` to `redisClient.getProduct` is executed in `future`.

This line `let product = await fetchProductFromCache(id)` in your `getProductById` resolves to `undefined` (which is your case here) because you did not return anything from `fetchProductFromCache`. That's because Javascript implicitly returns `undefined` for all function without return.

Note carefully, the return inside `cb` is returning to the `cb` function **not to** `fetchProductFromCache`.

You can achieve what you're trying to achieve by making `fetchProductFromCache` return a `Promise` like:

```
const fetchProductFromCache = async (id) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    redisClient.getProduct(id,  (error, product) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log('error', error);
        reject(error);
      } else if(product) {
        console.log('PRODUCT FROM CACHE ', product); //valid product is logged   
        resolve(product); //product returned to getProductById
      } else {
        console.log('NO PRODUCT FROM CACHE ');    
        resolve(null);
      }            
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you're returning from your redisClient.getProduct(), but not from your fetchProductFromCache().  As in your inner function is returning a value, but that value isn't being returned to the outer function, so the outer function is returning undefined.